# How to convert datetime fileds to UTC Datetime for existing data in the database?

Tags: sql-server, database, datetime, tsqlt, datetime-conversion

How can I change the Datetime values for the existing data to UTC Time?
Is any inbuilt SQL qry available to change?

Eg.
Existing Data in the table

```
CreatedON
2013-03-01 08:12:00.000
2013-03-01 13:15:18.000
2013-03-01 13:10:00.000
```

Need to convert this data to UTC time which is recorded as GMT Time during creation.
Any suggestions will be helpful

Comment: How can I identify the UTC time for existing data?
eg: 2013-03-01 08:12:00.000  wat will be the UTC Time for the given date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
declare @a datetime 
set @a='2013-03-01 08:12:00.000'

select  DateAdd(s,DateDiff(s, getdate(),getutcdate()),@a )
```

Comment: Will the qry be applicable for other dates like '2013-04-05 08:10:00', greater than the above dates?

Comment: @SESHI :: it'll work if you give @a=''2013-04-05 08:10:00.000' utc will be '2013-04-05 02:40:00.000'

Comment: Im getting the below result when I execute
'2013-04-05 07:10:00.000'

SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() - 2013-12-17 11:04:59.9216720 +01:00
getutcdate() - 2013-12-17 10:04:59.920 
Getdate() - 2013-12-17 11:04:59.920

Comment: i'm not getting what u'r telling?

Comment: you made any changes to this answer or is it jus fine?